Do "roil" and "royal" have the same pronunciation?
I found in the dictionary that “roil” is pronounced as /rɔɪl/, while “royal” is /ˈrɔɪ.əl/. However, I can hardly distinguish them when listening to the recordings.
Are they truly homophones, or is it just that I, as a non-native speaker, can’t hear the difference?

There is a difference, but even a native speaker might mishear one for the other if it's not obvious from context, so don't feel too bad about that. There's a sitcom called "The Royle family" whose name plays on this.

It could be that native speakers 'hear' the difference because of context, and further, we don't tend to say 'roil' that much in the UK where a Roil Family lives. ('mainly US' says Cambridge Dictionary).

Other words that, I have noticed, we don't say much in the UK include 'carom', 'whilom', and 'meld' (not that they have any confusing homophones).

The full OED has How is the word royal pronounced? British English
/ˈrɔɪəl/ ROY-uhl U.S. English /ˈrɔɪ(ə)l/ ROY-uhl. For roil they have
British English /rɔɪl/ royl U.S. English /rɔɪl/ royl. Meaning that according to them, the two are distinct for all Brits, but only some Americans. Personally, I don't really think the presence or absence of that final schwa (making it a three-vowel triphthong) is particularly heard or enunciated. People mostly just think there's a difference because of the spelling.

@MichaelHarvey Come on, the waters were roiling with fish.

Since "roil" is a verb while "royal" is an adjective, it's unlikely either would be used in a context where the other could be acceptable. So even if they're pronounced similarly, there would never be confusion.

When spoken slowly, the semi-consonant 'y' can be emphasised, but it isn't present in 'roil'.

Where's the /j/-type sound in the IPA? It's spelled with a "y". As in "yes" or "roy".

For me, these are homophones, or at least there is as much variation between speakers as there is between the pronunciation of the words. The words have very different meanings and are different parts of speech, so there it is easy to identify the words in context.  However, I'd be unable to tell which word was "roil" and which word "royal" in these two recordings from Wiktionary.

recording one
recording two

For me these are the same word. And even if some can detect a difference, it is too small to be of any consequence. There is no chance of being misunderstood.

Even so, my tongue is in a different position for each of them.  That might not make a very audible difference, but I regard it as a distinct pronunciation.  I speak American English.
